# Creating Calculated Member using MDX with OR condition

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am very new to MDX and SSAS.

I have a few fields in the measures group (C1, C2, C3, ... C5) with possible values of 1 or null, and I am trying to create a calculated member, which will be 1 if any one of these measures is 1.

Below is what I want to do, but do not know valid MDX script to perform this action.

```
iif(measures.c1=1 or measures.c2=1 or measures.c3=1 or measures.c4=1 or measures.c5=1, 1,0)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: More or less. If you are using Max aggregation it should be fine, in case of Sum or Count you have to use >1 instead. Could you tell more what do you want to achieve and what do you have there?

Answer (score 0):

How about add an additional column in db view side, you can populate the value for it by the " case when" statement based on the existed fields1/field2/field3 , and then add a measure in cube mapped on this new field without any mdx calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is what I am doing, as I could not figure out how to do the calculation in mdx, but I was wondering how to perform the calculation using mdx script.

Comment: If you do the same, then no need any mdx calculation, just query the added measure in the select statement only.